# Place PHP variable inside label

Tags: javascript, php

I have a question that's been bugging me since i can't really find an answer.

Say i run this:

```
<label><?php echo $c; ?></label>

<?php
$a = 100;
$b = 50;
$c = $a + $b;
?>
```

It will say it won't know $c because it get's declared later on in the script, is there a way that i can set a variable inside a label using PHP. I know php is very limited in its ways since it's just onload. But i've been wondering if there is a way for this without placing the label under the php script.

I'm also open for javascript ways. As long as i can set php variables inside labels.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It's not that i not know how to properly do it. $ before echo. But i was just wondering if there was a way to do it other way around...

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, why dont you just place the label after the php part?

Comment: use `printf("%d",($a+$b))` instead of echo , inside label

Comment: @diEcho that would print 0, which is not the expected result

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon see : http://codepad.viper-7.com/aVtyja

Comment: @diEcho that's easy, but it's not what the OP asked.. he wants to print it before instantiating it. try to put printf in the first line, and your example won't work

Comment: btw: this is one of the reasons to use a template / view system: do all calculations and fetching of data in a controller/model object, bind the results to the view / template, render the view script

Comment: @YUNOWORK I know it's the way to go to use it that way, but i've just been wondering if there is a possibility to not do it like that.

Comment: @N.B. What do you mean?

Comment: @Farewyth that means you have this language at your disposal that you deem LIMITED without even learning about its capabilities. Yes, you can create a piece of code that shows the HTML part first, then variable assigning second and it can work the way you imagined it. I know of at least 3 ways to do so from on top of my head just now, but what's actually dumb is that you want to complicate your life by doing something absolutely unintuitive. That's why the limitation doesn't exist within the language but at your mental flow of how this should be constructed. TL;DR; - change your approach.

Comment: @N.B. Where did I say i need this done for scripts im writing, nowhere. I was just wondering purely out of curiousity if something like this was possible without too much of a hassle. Sorry if you thought i ment that PHP is a very limited script, since i didn't mean it that way. I just ment that with my personal knowledge of PHP i found PHP limited for a situation like this. Since im nowhere experienced in PHP.

Comment: @Farewyth - the example you used is way too limited and in that case it makes *no sense* to perform what you asked. It is also impossible to echo a variable first and set its value later. What is possible is to create a templating solution, or closures that you invoke in proper sequence so that it appears, as you read the code, that echoing comes in first and setting the value comes later.

Comment: @N.B. Why didn't you answer something like this in the first place? Iwas purely asking out of curiousity nothing more. I know my example is stupid and i know there is no reason why i could possible want to set the label on top of the code in my example.

Comment: Ok, but the thing is, you obviously had a "click" or need for something similar. Problem occurs when you show a bad example to achieve something that actually MIGHT have some sense or use. Clear answer is "no, you can't echo variable before setting its value". What I'd do is include your entire problem that you're trying to solve because it doesn't appear to be a simple variable echoing before setting its value. If you do that, you'll probably get answers that'll either give you further ideas or full solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use variables after they are created!

```
    <?php
    $a = 100;
    $b = 50;
    $c = $a + $b;
    ?>

    <label><?php echo $c; ?></label>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, takes a bit of time to wrap my head around it. But after it sinks in, it's just a brilliant solution.

Comment: He is saying that he have to define $c after label (reason unknown)...

Comment: No he never says it has to.  he said it just is : `because it get's declared later on in the script`

Comment: And also `But i've been wondering if there is a way for this without placing the label under the php script.`

Comment: Oh snap, you got me *puts head down in shame

Comment: Let's assign `$c` to `$a + $b` before they exist too!

Comment: Aren't they trying to do something like that in CERN?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to javascript, you can do it like this:

First, give an `id` to the label:

```
<label id="label">...</label>
```

Then after in the php just add:

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "'.$c.'";</script>';
```

Comment: I know this works for a simple http request, and the OP asked for js alternative...but it is really ugly, and it will lead to problems if the script is loaded via a xhr (ajax) call

Answer (score 0):

```
is there a way that i can set a variable inside a label using PHP
```

Yes, try:

```
<label>
<?php 
$a = 100;
$b = 50;
$c = $a + $b; 
echo $c; 
?>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP programming it executes top-down. The variable must have a value before you can echo it:

```
<label><?php echo $c; ?></label>

<?php
$a = 100;
$b = 50;
$c = $a + $b;
?>
```

The above is incorrect because the variable $c has no value yet. You need to first execute the PHP code you have before the label like this:

?>

With the above $c now contains the sum of $a and $b.

Comment: Yeah exactly that's what i ment, i knew it was impossible to do but i was wondering if there was any (javascript) at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<label><?php label(); ?></label>

<?php
function label()
{
 $a = 100;
 $b = 50;
 $c = $a + $b;
 echo $c;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you really want to have the variables before the output, you can use a class for it::::

```
<?php
class some{
    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function really(){
        $a = 100;
        $b = 50;
        $c = $a + $b;
        return $c;
    }
}
?>
<?php $some = new some();?>
<label>This is C = <?php echo $some->really(); ?></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well comments are about the order of your lines but i guess you have to do it ... So..
1 - Give an id to label :

```
<label id="label4c"></label>
```

2 - Be sure you have jquery on this page..

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3 - Add this like after `$c = $a + $b;`

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
jQuery('#label4c').text('$c');
});</script>";
```

Comment: I would say is really bad practice to mix javascript with php >>> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript unless you have a better point?

Comment: Rolen Koh's answer looks better but the question is in javascript section. so mixing is what is he looking for i guess..

Comment: because there you are telling him to include anther library, for to use only `innerHTML `

Comment: is open for javascript ;) but what he had was script order confusion syndrome.. even if he did javascript, it wont work in the way he has it now ;)

Comment: his edit is saying he is looking for solution without taking label below $c.. :) so he got few ways to do it :)

Comment: yeah, but is okay, brings back old memories lol

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a real reason why you would need to do that, but it was a stimulating exercise. As many others already told you, you can't do that in simple PHP, because the script is executed top-down, and you're trying to print the variable before its assignment.

You asked for javascript solutions, and here's one that shows you the right value after the dom is completely loaded:

```
<label><script>
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    document.write(c);
   }
}
</script></label>

<?php
$a = 100;
$b = 50;
$c = $a + $b;
?>
<script>var c = <?php echo $c;?>;</script>
```

The code is pretty naive and I don't suggest to use it in a real environment (also, is couldn't work in any device), because it's not well written nor easily maintainable. I'd rather tell you to consider your flow and understand if you really need to do what you think you need (writing a variable before its assignment). I definitely believe there's a way to re-engineer your script to write a better code: you're probably overcomplicating something simple. Good luck!

Comment: It purely an example script and not something that needs to be done, i was purely asking out of curiousity if something was possible to echo $ before assigning it.

Comment: Great, that was my guess. This is a way you can do that (with javscript, as you asked)

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you should try this via script**

```
<label id="p1"></label>

<?php
$a = 100;
$b = 50;
$c = $a + $b;
?>

<script>
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="<?php echo $c; ?>";
</script>
```